# Delete urls from autocomplete with a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm developping a chrome extension which delete urls from history, but the autocomplete of those urls still works. I would like to delete them from autocomplete also.

I use those two function :
- chrome.browsingData.remove
- chrome.history.deleteUrl

All helps are welcomed !